# Why don't I get keyUp / keyDown events for control characters in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsview, keyboard-events

My **NSView** window receives key up / key down events for all keys except for **Shift**, **Alt**, **Cmd** and a few others... How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifier keys are a special case.  If you want to know when they're pressed or released, implement the responder method `-flagsChanged:`